# Exercise 3.22 from W. Lawvere. Sets For Mathematics.

Tags: category-theory

I can't solve Exercise 3.22 from W. Lawvere - Sets For Mathematics book.

> **Exercise 3.22.** Show that for any $A$, $1 \times A \simeq A$.

The exercise has the following hint.

> *Hint:* To show one of the equations requires using the uniqueness clause in the definition of product.

One page earlier the author gives the following definition

> **Definition 3.20.**
>   In any category, a **product** of two objects $A$ and $B$ is a pair of giving mappings 
>   $$ A \xleftarrow{\pi_A} P \xrightarrow{\pi_B} B$$
>   such that
>   $$\forall X,\ f\colon X \to A,\  g\colon X \to B\ \ \exists! h\colon X \to P\ [f = \pi_Ah \text{ and } g = \pi_Bh]$$
>   as in [the following commutative diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P6Lu1.png).

I'm trying to replace $X$ with $A$, $B$ with $1$ and $f$ with $1_A$ in the diagram above. It gives me $\pi_Ah = 1_A$. Now I'm stuck at showing $h\pi_A =1_{A \times 1}$.

Comment: That's exactly where the uniqueness clause intervenes. $h\pi_A$ is a map from $1\times A$ to itself : you know what maps to $1\times A$ are, don't you ?

Comment: Sorry, I don't get your point. Can you clarify a little bit, please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$h\pi_A : 1\times A\to 1\times A$ is entirely determined by the composites with $\pi_1$ and $\pi_A$, by the *uniqueness* part of the definition of product.

Now $1$ is terminal, so $\pi_1\circ $whatever can only be one thing.

What is $\pi_A\circ h \circ \pi_A$ ?

Do you know another interesting map $1\times A\to 1\times A$ that has the same projections ?

Comment: how does $\pi_1$ get used in the proof? I'm trying to imagine the case when we have $\mathbf{2} \times A$, it seems like we should still be able to "forget" the first coordinate and get $\mathbf{2} \times A \cong A$.

Comment: No : the morphism $\pi_2\circ h\circ \pi_A$ will not necessarily the correct one (plus : how do you get a map $A\to 2$ ? ). $\pi_1$ is used because $\pi_1\circ h\circ \pi_A$ can only be one thing, and it has to be the same thing as $\pi_1\circ id$

Comment: hmm, i see, thank you. i was thinking we could choose $\pi_2$ based on $h$ but obviously we can't because it is against the definition

Comment: actually, continuing to think about it, i guess the biggest issue with my argument (or at least my understanding) was that there is of course no assurance of surjectivity of sets in the map from $X$ to $P$, since $|P| > |X|$ unless at least one of the two factors is $1$. dumb mistake on my part. thanks for the clarification :)